# Connect to a Wireless Network with My Friend

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My friend is less than 10 kilometers away from me. I want to create a wireless network between him and myself to share file storage, transfer files, maybe chat, etc. What are the requirements to achieve this? What type of hardware is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your distance requirements, most conventional wireless solutions will not work for you. In most cases you would need to create line of sight between the two receivers.
Your options are as follows:

1. Between the two of you create a network of repeaters. You will need a large number of these to obtain the distance you are looking for. (Not Ideal)
2. Use of a satellite provider. You can use a paid service, hook up satellite dishes to your homes and talk to each other over the internet.
3. Powerful Directed Antennas. These would need to be mounted high and be capable of seeing each other (literally line of sight). In this case you will have to account for curvature of the earth. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight_propagation)

Most likely you would opt for the latter approach but I do warn you that it is costly and you would most likely need to build towers in order to get the distance necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the through answer. My friend lives in a 4-story apartment. I think we will be able to use antenna. How much do you think it would cost? Could you name some candidates? (antenna, etc.)

Comment: Your best option for antennas would probably be Ubiquiti airMAX Nanobridge M units. They advertise a range of about 20KM with speeds of 150Mb/s. I've used them before and they work excellently.
(http://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/nanobridgem/nbm_ds_web.pdf)  

Edit: Didn't see your price comment.
I've seen them advertised for 250 Euros. Depends on your area.
(http://www.wifigear.co.uk/ubiquiti-nanobridge-m-airmax-mimo-wireless-ptp-kit)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple but costs. You need wave amplifiers(repeaters) or powerful antenna instead of your modems antenna.

If you have two powerful antenna, you can create Peer-to-Peer network.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know this but just for clarification, I am assuming if your friend has an internet connection already, then creating a VPN would be simplest and cheapest option without need of anything extra (baside basic VPN software)

Otherwise, the line of sight wireless option is the choice here, as pointed out already.

Comment: We both have internet connection, however the speed is low (2Mbps). We want to use this connection to create a private network to share files. Something like a shared media center.